# What's the physical meaning of the kinetic Green's function?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, condensed-matter, many-body, greens-functions

I'm struggling to understand the physical meaning of some of the Green's functions relations. Especially the relation known as the Kinetic Green's function. Which by definition is the sum $ G^{K} = G^{>} + G^{<} $. Any help would be very appreciated. I'd also appreciate some references which can help me better understand the physical meaning of all Green's functions. Thank you very much.

Comment: What are the definitions of $G^{>}$ and $G^{<}$?

Comment: $ G^{>} (x,t,x',t') = -i < \psi(x,t) \psi^{\dagger} (x',t')> $ Where $ \psi$ are the field operators in the Heinsenberg picture and $ G^{<} = - ( G^{>} )* wiith * being the complex conjugate.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know. But it looks like twice the real part of Green's function. It would be nice to know the context where you read it.